# Kali linux regular user session not supported

Tags: linux, firefox

Opened the terminal with sudo.
Dehilighted dynamic chain, amd added sock5 proxy(same as socks4) in nano /etc/proxychains.conf
When runnig command proxychains firefox [www.duckduckgo.com](http://www.duckduckgo.com), it shows Runnig firefox as root in a regular users session is not supported($Xauthority is /home/muhammed/.Xauthority which is owned by muhammed.)
I need to open firefox in this way, pls help me

Answer (score 0):

i m a newbie and i m not sure about this but it worked for me .

when i open my terminal it shows 'root@kali:/#' . enter command 'exit' to exit as root user . then it shows 'username@kali:/#' . Then enter ur command 'proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com' , the browser should open.

or change the ownership of file .Xauthority to root using chown command . then enter ur command and it opens the browser